# Debian script - reboot proces if remote connection failed

Tags: linux, debian, reverse-tunnel

I am trying to figure out how to manage my debian and make it to reload script in /etc/init.d if the remote, reverese connection is not responding

what I have at the moment is:

```
root@pwnpi:~# netstat -nat
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State

tcp        0    512 10.28.4.115:34233       xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:31337    ESTABLISHED
```

and I would like to reload script /etc/init.d/reverseshell if this connection is not ESTABLISHED or LISTEN

Can anyone help with that?

Comment: The term "reboot" is usually taken to mean the entire system. Do you mean *restarting* a process (through its init script) based on some criteria? Please [edit] as appropriate to clarify.

Comment: Maybe [this item on UNIX & Linux SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122484/linux-centos-6-restart-network-service-after-lost-ping) answers your question? Also: what's the point in rebooting your computer when a networking connection is lost? If the datacenter has a networking outage (which shouldn't occur often), your server will continually reboot. It might be better just to restart the networking services... Finally: what have you already tried? Where are you stuck? SE is **not** a scripting service.

Comment: I need to scan our internal network /12 this weekend and the solution I have (reverse shell) is failing on me every few hours.

Answer (score 0):

Make a *cron* for that command

```
lsof -i4TCP@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:31337 -sTCP:ESTABLISHED,LISTEN >/dev/null 2>&1 || /etc/init.d/reverseshell restart
```

**PS**: don't be evil :-)